# Example of splitting family

Tags: set-theory, examples-counterexamples, cardinals

The splitting number is the cardinal defined by:

$$
\mathfrak{s}=\min\{|S|:S\subseteq[\omega]^\omega\wedge (S \ \text{is a splitting family})\}
$$

Where being splitting means: $\forall X\in[\omega]^\omega\exists Y\in S(|X\cap Y|=|X\setminus Y|=\omega)$.

I know that $\mathfrak{s}$ is not countable and $\leq2^{\aleph_0}$.

My problem is I need find a splitting family to justify your definition. Can someone help me?

Comment: Given a single infinite set $X$, have you tried finding a set $Y$ that splits it? Then you could just gather those together...

Comment: Do you see that $[\omega]^{\omega}$ is a splitting family? How about $[\omega]^{\omega} \setminus \{X\}$ for $X \in [\omega]^{\omega}$?

Comment: @StefanMesken yes I see. Thanks for your help.

Comment: By an Iterated Forcing construction  we can show that it is consistent with ZFC that $\mathfrak s$ can be any regular uncountable cardinal not exceeding $2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet it can also be singular btw (of uncountable cofinality).